# Question about the application of Rule of Substitution.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Working on the book: David Gries. "*The Science of Programming*" (p. 34)

The following definition appears:

(2.2.1) **Rule of Substitution.** Let $e1=e2$ be an equivalence and $E(p)$ be a proposition, written as a function of one of its identifiers $p$. Then $E(e1)=E(e2)$ and $E(e2)=E(e1)$ are also equivalences. $\square$

> **Example.** We show that $(b \to c) = (\lnot c \to \lnot b)$ is an equivalence (an explanation of the format follows):

\begin{align*}
  & b \to c \\
  =& \lnot b \lor c \tag{Implication}\\
  =& c \lor \lnot b \tag{Commutativity}\\
  =& \lnot\lnot c \lor \lnot b\tag{Negation}\\
  =& \lnot c \to \lnot b\tag{Implicationn}\\
\end{align*}

> This is read as follows. First, lines 1 and 2 indicate that $b \to c$ is equivalent to $\lnot b \lor c$, by virtue of the rule of Substitution and the law of Implication.

Clearly, an instance of the *law of Implication* is used in the first equality:

$$ b \to c = \lnot b \lor c \tag{*}$$

However...why is the Rule of Substitution being mentioned? Perhaps, the author is taking $$E(p)=p\\e1=b \to c\\e2=\lnot b \lor c$$ and then applies that Rule to achieve equality (*) ? Or, is that application superfluous ?

Comment: Very confused... $E(p)$ is a formula of propositional logic with an occurrence of the prop variable $p$, like e.g. $p \lor q$. The Subst Rule mean that if we have two equivalent formulas, like e.g. $r \to s$ and $\lnot r \lor s$, the result of substituting them into $E(p)$ in place of $p$ will produce two equivalent formulas: $(r \to s) \lor q \equiv (\lnot r \lor s) \lor q$

Comment: The author is proving a result through a chain of equivelences: $A \equiv B$ and $B \equiv C$, then $A \equiv C$. And you are right: if we have a rule asserting that $b \to c \equiv \lnot b \lor c$, we have already the equivalence, and we do not subst anything.

Comment: The Subst Rule in needed with Negation (presumably $p \equiv \lnot \lnot p$) to move from $c \lor \lnot b$ to the equiv $\lnot \lnot c \lor \lnot b$

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA ! I always appreciate your fantastic and detailed insight. Now, it is clear.